# Spring bean scopes in web application context hierarhy

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

I have spring root web context configured in web.xml file.
I also have several child contexts with this parent. All child contexts are created manually:

```
 ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"ApplicationContext/beans.xml"}, rootApplicationContext);
```

I want to manage session and request scoped beans in this child context.

How to create and configure child contexts correctly to make them able to handle web application scopes?

Now I have following error while trying to autowire session scoped bean (obviously):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope 'session'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have is that

> session-scope : Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a HTTP Session. Only valid in the context of a **web-aware Spring ApplicationContext**.

And your `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` is not *web-aware*.

I suggest you to go to `GenericWebApplicationContext` instead of `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`

You can try something like this:

```
GenericWebApplicationContext context = new GenericWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
context.setParent(rootApplicationContext);
XmlBeanDefinitionReader xmlReader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(context);
xmlReader.loadBeanDefinitions(new ClassPathResource("ApplicationContext/beans.xml"));
context.refresh();
```

Spring javadoc is useful source:

- [GenericApplicationContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/GenericApplicationContext.html)

Comment: context.setParent(rootApplicationContext) - I missed that line )

Comment: When I do that, I get a `Cannot resolve ServletContextResource without ServletContext`. This is resolved by passing the servlet context into the new application context from the root application context (my current bean was made `ApplicationContextAware` for this purpose).